Visual Studio: Getting a "reportMissingModuleSource" error, and can't fix
enter image description here
I cannot figure out why I am getting this error when my requirements are satisfied and the modules are installed. I believe the PATH is correct. I've manually imported these modules into the project environment and still have no luck.
Is my current version of Python (3.12) not compatible with these packages/modules?
Please help!
Updated python, pip.
Verified modules and packages are installed.
Checked PATH.
No luck!

From such a generic error it is hard to determine what's causing it, so I would recommend you to follow general and common solutions. You should start checking that you are using the correct Python Interpreter in Visual Studio, by going Tools > Options > Python > Python Enviroments and make sure you selected the right one.
Then, open the integrated terminal in Visual Studio and activate the environment (if you haven`t already activated it). Then, run the following commands:
python --version
pip list

This will confirm you if you have the correct python version and if pandas is installed.
If everything is allright at this point, try reinstalling the package by running this in the terminal:
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas

If it still doesn't work, check the PYTHONPATH, although you already checked it, it won't hurt to check again to see if you're missing something.
At this point, I hope something worked off, if it still doesn't, consider updating Visual Studio or creating a Virtual Environment, or you could also check for compatibility issues, as Python 3.12 is relatively new and might not load pandas correctly (although it generally should). Try using an earlier version of Python, too.
Hope it works!

"From such a generic error it is hard to determine what's causing it [...]": Please don't answer a vague question. Ask for clarification/debugging details instead.

As it turns out, it was indeed a version issue and uninstalling/installing seems to have removed the modulemissing error has resolved. However, I am now getting an error "module not accessed", although again, my environment and packages seem to be altogether. I'm searching for a solution, but do you have any ideas? Thanks again for your attention and help.

RESOLVED! Python 3.12 was not functioning correctly with Visual Studio. Using an older version of Python (3.11) and uninstalling/installing pandas and other modules solved the problem.
